# Resize query not working as intended

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to increase the height of html element ONLY when the window resizes but the script runs when the window is not resized. I have looked at multiple posts online and have tried other scripts but nothing seems to work.

I am including the script in master page because I want this behavior on every page.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FuzionLogin.Master.cs" Inherits="Fuzion_Login_V2.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testing.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var timer;

            $(window).resize(function () {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('html').css("height", "150%");
                });
            }).resize();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageInfo" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because of this:

```
}).resize();
```

This triggers the `.resize()` on DOM ready event. So, you have to change it to:

```
$(function () {
    var timer;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('html').css("height", "150%");
        });
    }); // <----remove the trigger here.
});
```

Some changes as per your comment:

```
$(function () {
    var timer, $win = $(window);
    var win_w = $win.width(); // cache the orig width
    var win_h = $win.height(); // cache the orig height
    $win.resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if($win.width() === win_w && $win.height() === win_h){ // check if width height are equal to cached ones
              $('html').css("height", "100%");
            }else{
              $('html').css("height", "150%");
            }
        });
    }); // <----remove the trigger here.
});
```

Comment: Jai, thank you for the answer. This works, however when the window does not return to original size. How can I set the html size to 100% back?

Comment: Well you can use to have a if condition to have a check on the window height/width then you can change it back to 100%.

Comment: Is there an example you could provide? I am still very new to jquery.

Comment: check if this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.